# How to find item between two items in list?

Tags: python, string, list

I have the following list

```
a = [['-','k','-','x','k','x','-', 'k'],
     ['k','k','-','x','k','-','-', 'k'],
     ['k','-','-','x','k','-','x', 'k'],
     ['x','k','x','x','k','-','-', '-']]
```

If you see the list above valid items (sublist) in the outer list are only where there is at least one 'x' between 'k'. You can have more than two 'k' but it must have 'x' between them.

I want to find if 'x' exists between two of 'k'.

How to implement in python?

I want to filter valid inner list. Basically, I am trying to generate the various lists using permuting '-', 'x', and 'k'. The list is only valid if there is at least one 'x' between 'k'. You can have more than two 'k' but it must have 'x' between them.

For example `a[0]` is valid as there is always 'x' between 'k'.
`a[1]` not valid.
`a[2]` is valid.
`a[3]` is valid.

So final result should be

```
a_filtered = [['-','k','-','x','k','x','-', 'k'],
     ['k','-','-','x','k','-','x', 'k'],
     ['x','k','x','x','k','-','-', '-']].
```

Any hint or help is appreciated.

Comment: Can there also be a `-` between the same two `k`? Which are the valid/invalid items in your sample data, and why?

Comment: Nick, I updated the question.  It can have as many dashes but it has to have x between two 'k'  `[k,-,-,k]` is not valid. Whereas `[k,x,-k]` is valid. Think of x as a wall. and - as empty space. if x between two ks then it is safe. Otherwise not.

Comment: So there has to be an `x` between *every* pair of `k`?

Comment: Yes. Not necessary next to it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it could be solved using str.join and regex as follows:

```
import re
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [['-','k','-','x','k','x','-', 'k'],
         ['k','k','-','x','k','-','-', 'k'],
         ['k','-','k','-','x','k','-','-','k'], # added to check 'k' + arbitrary length of non-x + 'k'
         ['k','-','-','x','k','-','x', 'k'],
         ['x','k','x','x','k','-','-', '-']]
    pat = re.compile("k[^x]*k")
    b = [lst for lst in a if not pat.match("".join(lst))]
    # show what happens
    a_strs = ["".join(lst) for lst in a]
    for a_str in a_strs:
        a_match_not_allowed = pat.match(a_str)
        print(f"[main] str: {a_str}, not allowed: {a_match_not_allowed}")
    print(*b, sep="\n")
```

Core code:

```
pat = re.compile("k[^x]*k")
b = [lst for lst in a if not pat.match("".join(lst))]
```

Result:

```
[main] str: -k-xkx-k, not allowed: None
[main] str: kk-xk--k, not allowed: <re.Match object; span=(0, 2), match='kk'>
[main] str: k-k-xk--k, not allowed: <re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='k-k'>
[main] str: k--xk-xk, not allowed: None
[main] str: xkxxk---, not allowed: None
['-', 'k', '-', 'x', 'k', 'x', '-', 'k'],
['k', '-', '-', 'x', 'k', '-', 'x', 'k'],
['x', 'k', 'x', 'x', 'k', '-', '-', '-']
```

You could avoid matching arbitrary length of non-x characters between k by using above regex.

Answer (score 1):

After your comment I messed around a little more:

```py
[line for line in a if "kk" not in "".join(line).replace("-", "")]
```

Comment: Yes. but will it handle this scenario?     `-k-----kx` ? or `-k-xk--k` This both are invalid set.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood. In this case you might want to use regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

a = [['-','k','-','x','k','x','-', 'k'],
     ['k','k','-','x','k','-','-', 'k'],
     ['k','-','-','x','k','-','x', 'k'],
     ['x','k','x','x','k','-','-', '-']]
     
a_filltered = a.copy() # a_fillered is same as a
for sublist in a_filltered: # loop through all lists
    without_dash=list(filter(lambda c: c != '-', sublist)) # remove all dashes
    new_string=''.join(without_dash) # make a string from list e.g. from ['k','k'..] to 'kk'
    if(re.search("kk", new_string)): # use regex to find if there are 2 k in a row, which means there isn't x between
        a_filltered.remove(sublist) # remove if it is invalid

print(a_filltered)
```

Answer (score 0):

If we write a little generator to yield all slices in a list bounded by `'k'` on either end:

```
def grps(li, tgt):
    indicies=[i for i, e in enumerate(li) if e==tgt]
    for slce in zip(indicies, indicies[1:]):
        if slce[0]+1==slce[1]:
            continue
        yield li[slce[0]:slce[1]+1]
```

Then finding if a slice has `'x'` in it is trivial:

```
[sl for sl in a if all('x' in grp for grp in grps(sl, 'k'))]
# [['-', 'k', '-', 'x', 'k', 'x', '-', 'k'], 
   ['k', '-', '-', 'x', 'k', '-', 'x', 'k'], 
   ['x', 'k', 'x', 'x', 'k', '-', '-', '-']]
```